# How to pass a file through two forms

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload

I have the following form that allows uploading a file:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="page1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">>
 CSV list: <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I go to my action/submit page I can retrieve the file and the temp location of the file, but I need to send it through again to a new page, so I do the following:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php" name="details" >
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="<? echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Insert Into Database">
</form>
```

This doesn't work because the temp file is already gone.... how can I pass the file through?

Comment: seems pointless, explain the big picture

Comment: upload a csv, have the person verify some on screen data, they say looks good.. click the button and do a full upload where i put it in a database

Comment: no need to upload it twice, just move it to your own temp before verification, and clean that out periodical

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to rethink how you are getting this data. If it was me, I would want to have the first form upload the file to a temporary directory and pass the path to the file through a $_REQUEST. Then use a hidden input field pass the file path name through PHP and if they confirm their selection on the second form, do whatever you want with the file using the file's path. This means you don't have to upload two files(not efficient) and you can pass the data onto the second form.

Comment: which is effectively what I was trying to do in the code above - but the temp name is gone by the time i get to the next page...

Comment: any file uploaded to system temp is deleted after the script finishes, you have to move it to your own temp (as i said above)